# Small responsive images appear blurred when collapsed on tablet

Tags: css, image, responsive-design, media-queries

I have a web page with a row 1200px wide with some 3/4 columns, each one holding an image, that is each image may be 300/400 px wide. On collapse, below the breakpoint (768), images appear blurred because they are scaled to 768px in width.
I wanted to keep things as small as possible, however I think I'll have to use larger images, shrinking them with media queries on large desktop view and 1:1 (almost) on tablets.

Any thought?

Comment: Using larger images will achieve what you want, but you might also want to consider using media queries to detect retina display devices and hide/show images if they meet the correct conditions. See: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/retina-display-media-query/

Also, you could try a jquery library like this: http://luis-almeida.github.io/unveil/. I haven't used it myself but it looks like it'll do what you need and will only load images when they're requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can upload the images to 768px if that is the biggest they get. If you have a lot of images and worry about download time for slow connections or bandwidth from server, consider only load images depending on resolution.

You can read more here:
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/responsive/picture-element/

You can also google responsive images and see what would fit you best, or build your own solution if you are into that :)